# Convert Binary to Float

Tags: c, floating-point

I'm trying to assign a float from a raw binary string, but I don't get what I would expect.

```
int main()
{
    char recBuffer[] = {0x44, 0x42, 0x96, 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78};
    float tempFloat;
    int position = 3;

    printf( "recBuffer=0x%x%x%x%x\n", recBuffer[3], recBuffer[4], recBuffer[5], recBuffer[6]);
    memcpy( &tempFloat, recBuffer + position, 4 );
    printf( "tempFloat=%f (0x%x)\n", tempFloat, tempFloat );
    return 0;
}
```

My output looks like:

```
recBuffer=0x12345678
tempFloat=*************************************** (0x40000000)
```

The above procedure works for integers:

```
int main()
{
    char recBuffer[] = {0x44, 0x42, 0x96, 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78};
    int tempFloat;
    int position = 3;

    printf( "recBuffer=0x%x%x%x%x\n", recBuffer[3], recBuffer[4], recBuffer[5], recBuffer[6]);
    memcpy( &tempFloat, recBuffer + position, 4 );
    printf( "tempFloat=%d (0x%x)\n", tempFloat, tempFloat );
    return 0;
}
```

with an output:

```
recBuffer=0x12345678
tempFloat=2018915346 (0x78563412)
```

(I'm aware of Endianness.)

I've tried to assign the float directly, but I still get something weird as an output (what do all the *'s mean?).

```
int main()
{
    char recBuffer[] = {0x44, 0x42, 0x96, 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78};
    float* tempFloat;
    int position = 3;

    printf( "recBuffer=0x%x%x%x%x\n", recBuffer[3], recBuffer[4], recBuffer[5], recBuffer[6]);
    tempFloat = (float*)(recBuffer + position);
    printf( "tempFloat=%f (0x%x)\n", *tempFloat, *tempFloat );
    return 0;
}
```

with output:

```
recBuffer=0x12345678
tempFloat=*************************************** (0x40000000)
```

Any binary sequence should give me an output, as 0x78563412 = 1.73782443614495040019632524267E34. I'm not sure why 0x40000000 = *****. It should be 2.0E0.
What am I doing wrong?! Any help would be appreciated!

(unfortunately I'm working on an old QNX machine, with no debugger. Just simple printf()'s to help me along).

Comment: I think you mean raw "byte" string, not "binary"

Comment: The `%x` format won't print the `float` because the call to `printf()` automatically converts the `float` to a `double` (and anything shorter than `int` to `int`).  What happens when you use `%e` instead of `%f`?

Comment: I get:
`recBuffer=0x12345678
tempFloat=*************************************** (1.737824e+034)`
Amazing. It's never where you'd expect. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf( "tempFloat=%d (0x%x)\n", tempFloat, tempFloat);
                          ^                     |
                          |                     |
                          +---------------------+
```

The [`%x`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) specifier is useful for integer numbers but you're passing a `float` value to the `printf`. So the output is not a meaningful value.

Comment: That did it!
`recBuffer=0x12345678

tempFloat=*************************************** (1.737824e+034)`

I still don't understand why %f would return ****, but I'm happy memcpy() does what I'd expect. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){
    char recBuffer[] = {0x44, 0x42, 0x96, 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78};
    float tempFloat;
    int position = 3;

    printf( "recBuffer=0x%x%x%x%x\n", recBuffer[3], recBuffer[4], recBuffer[5], recBuffer[6]);
    memcpy( &tempFloat, recBuffer + position, 4 );
    printf( "tempFloat=%f (0x%x)\n", tempFloat, *(unsigned*)&tempFloat );
    return 0;
}
/*
recBuffer=0x12345678
tempFloat=17378244361449504000000000000000000.000000 (0x78563412)
*/
```

Comment: %f still gives me *******, but using your advice:
`printf( "tempFloat=%e (0x%x)\n", tempFloat, *(unsigned*)&tempFloat );` allows me to get the raw hex value!: `recBuffer=0x12345678
tempFloat=1.737824e+034 (0x78563412)`. That helps me alot, thanks!